# jQuery and VS2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

Can someone provide me with a HelloWorld JQuery sample app using *VS2010* and list out any manual steps such as installation and setting of references/placement of script files necessary to make it work? It would also be great if intellisense would work, so if manual steps are necessary to get it to work, that would be nice to know too.

Most of the stuff I see is on VS2008 and I suspect that it is different/simpler in VS2010.

Update. I am still looking for a sample Hello World app. When I run the following I get:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>JQuery Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#msgid1").html("This is Hello World by JQuery 1");
        });

    </script>
    <body>

    This is Hello World by HTML

    <div id="msgid1">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I get the error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; MS-RTC EA 2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 16:06:23 UTC


    Message: Invalid character
    Line: 1
    Char: 1
    Code: 0
    URI: file:///c:/inetpub/wwwroot/jquery.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in the HEAD of your masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

For intellisense, check here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

That's about it.